# Background not repeating on iPhone browser

Tags: iphone, css, html, mobile-safari, background-image

So having a little browser compatibility issue, but only on the iPhone and iPad Safari browsers :(

***Site:*** http://s433108212.onlinehome.us

My client wanted the space background in the header to stretch past the 1000px area I have set for the header. So my solution was to just create another wrapper that went 100% with a background:repeat-x image of the space to tile.

Well it works in every single browser on PC and Mac, except for the iPhone and iPad, it's really puzzling me because it looks like in the screenshots below that the tiled background image in the space_stretch_bg wrapper is **1)** pushed over to the left and **2)** not tiling so **3)** you see white behind the 1000px fixed banner above it :/

[image]
[image]

Anyone else run into this?

CSS:

```
body { 
    width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;
    background-image:url('../img/clouds.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat; 
}
.wrapper_bg {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; height: 350px; 
    background-image:url('../img/bg_tile.gif'); 
    background-repeat:repeat-x; 
}
.space_stretch_bg { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100px; width: 100%; height: 250px; 
    background-image:url('../img/space_banner_big.jpg'); 
    background-repeat:repeat-x; background-position:center; 
}
.container1000 { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 1000px; top: -100px; 
    margin:auto; 
}
#content_container { 
    position: absolute; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    top: 350px; padding: 20px; 
    background: #fff 
}
```

Shortened HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="wrapper_bg">
<div class="space_stretch_bg">
<div class="container1000">

    <!-- nav_bar -->

    <div id="banner">
        <a href="http://s433108212.onlinehome.us/index.php" title="Athena's Web">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>Athena's Web</h1>
                <h2>Carpe Noctem</h2>
                <img src="http://s433108212.onlinehome.us/img/athenas_web_logo_no_text.png" alt="Athena's Web Carpe Noctem"/>
            </div>
         </a>

        <div id="social_media">

            <!-- social_icons -->

        </div><!-- social_media -->

        </div><!-- banner -->
        <!-- End Header -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: it's because of wrapper_bg background that gets smaller. It's behind space_stretch_bg. Give wrapper_bg `min-width: 1000px` because your content_container is 1000px.

You can see the white space also on your pc browser if you make the browser smaller.

Comment: And that fixed it! However now my layout is broken in all browsers, the design fixes to the left instead of being centered: http://s433108212.onlinehome.us/ I had to put that min-width on the space_stretch_bg instead of the wrapper because I need the wrapper at 100%

Comment: I did this on .space_stretch_bg: min-width: 1000px; width: 100%; and it works in browsers and the iPhone now :) thx